# Pause and resume AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My Android app handle the business logic in a thread implemented by using AsyncTask which is now call the BL thread.

BL want to prompt user to enter some personal data (name, password...) by adding a Fragment on the UI thread. At this point I want to stop the BL thread, wait for user to enter their name, password..., press the OK button and then continue the BL thread.

How can I achieve that on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing AsynkTask is not best choice. Still you may find example of pausing AsynkTask in Google sample app [DisplayingBitmaps](https://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/DisplayingBitmaps.zip) in `ImageWorker` class.

```
private class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsynkTask<Void, Void, BitmapDrawable> {
  @Override
  protected BitmapDrawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
    synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
      while (mPauseWork && !isCancelled()) {
        try {
          mPauseWorkLock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}

public void setPauseWork(boolean pauseWork) {
  synchronized(mPauseWorkLock) {
    mPauseWork = pauseWork;
    if (!mPauseWork) {
      mPauseWorkLock.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is supposed to do a single/one time task.

That is not a good use of AsyncTask. AsyncTasks should do work and be done, not try hanging around.

You will find dirty solutions on the web with Thread.sleep() for example. Those are really bad solutions.

If you need two different process you should create two different tasks

For your issue you can cancel() your background thread or asynsTask, and when needed create a new one with updated parameters maybe

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it all inside one AsyncTask..

When creating the fragment with the OK button define new button listener which create new thread and will do the rest of the work.

You might want to use service or service intent and not AsyncTask for that so you could seperate the task to seprate functions and still maintain the background running.